# Getting this error when trying to use flatpak, “No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’”

Tags: debian, package-management, flatpak

I am trying to use flatpak and whenever I try and install anything I get this error stating:

```
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’
```

I have googled this error and it seems that this occurs when flatpak does not know about this repo. This common solution seems to be to run the following:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

To add the repo however after doing this I am still seeing the same issue.

When I run `flatpak remotes` I get the following:

```
flatpak remotes    
Name    Options    
flathub system
```

I think this means that the repo is known to flatpak. Finally if I run:

```
flatpak remote-add flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

I get an error stating:

```
Error: Remote flathub already exists
```

Does anyone know how to go about rectifying this?

Comment: Could you try to reinstall flatpak?

Comment: I will give it a go.

Comment: So I did an apt remove and apt purge, reinstalled and the problem is still present.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you trying to install flatpaks using the --user flag? If so, you need to also use that flag to add the repo:

```
flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```