# How to solve error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’

Tags: flatpak

How to solve this flatpak error?:

```
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’
```

Steps taken so far:

- Install flatpak: `sudo install flatpak`
- Trying to install an app: `flatpak install flathub dev.lapce.lapce`

Expected at this point: the app is installed.

Actually, the error above is shown.

Comment: Note: there is a similarly looking question asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1755709/getting-this-error-when-trying-to-use-flatpak-no-remote-refs-found-similar-to    However, that one is different because it's about the user/root mismatch, whereas this issue is about the most general and standard setup.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```sh
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Explanation:
It seems that flatpak (the package manager) tries to decouple itself from flathub (the repository) too much. The command above sets the "default" repository.